# problem on java calendar function

Tags: java, internationalization, calendar, timezone, date-format

I declared `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Malaysia"));
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MMMMM.dd hh:mm aaa");
```

or:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+08:00"));
```

Then I call this:

```
sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

but result is not in correct time zone (+8 hours). What could be the problem?

Comment: `calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));`

Comment: @John, still the same, the ID got problem = =

Comment: `Date` instance returns time string in default time zone.[This link will help you](http://techinitiatives.blogspot.com/2007/07/getting-java-date-in-another-timezone.html)

Comment: @John, i still not understand how to make it work= =

Comment: @newbie: As I said, the problem is Date is GMT based. It will always print in Default time zone (`TimeZone.getDefault()`), unless you pass your desired time zone to the formatter object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are going to perform Date/Time related calculations, there is no point in instantiating Calendar with given TimeZone. After calling Calendar's `getTime()` method, you will receive `Date` object, which is timezone-less either way (GMT based, actually).

What you need to do, is to set `TimeZone` for formatter instead. And also do not bother with passing your own format, there is a built-in already:

```
    // get current time
    // you could just as well use Date now = new Date();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Locale for formatter
    Locale malaysianLocale = new Locale("ms", "MY");
    // Default date and time format for Malaysia
    DateFormat defaultMalaysianFormatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, malaysianLocale);
    // This step is crucial
    TimeZone malaysianTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
    defaultMalaysianFormatter.setTimeZone(malaysianTimeZone);

    System.out.println(defaultMalaysianFormatter.format(now.getTime()));
```

This prints something like `10 Mei 2011 2:30:05 AM`, which I believe is your desired result.

Comment: my output is 2011 05 10 10:37:30 only i want dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss, able to custome this?

Comment: You can use SimpleDateFormat to do that. So you can code something like `SimpleDateFormat formtatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", malaysianLocale);   formatter.setTimeZone(malaysianTimeZone);   formatter.format(now.getTime());`. I would recommend against custom patterns, but if you really need to do this, this is how.

Answer (score 1):

Time zone id should be set as `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur`. `Date.toString()` always returns time string using default time zone. But your default time zone is different.

```
    Calendar tzCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, tzCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, tzCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, tzCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tzCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tzCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, tzCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tzCal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    System.out.println("Current Time = " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: @John, so i need to customize time instead of using default?

Comment: @newbie: yes. you need to customize it.

Comment: @John: same with previous, the correct one suppose +08:00 hour

Comment: @newbie: previous? post your timezone :`System.out.println("Current Timezone=" + TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());`

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeZone.getTimeZone()` call is incorrect. You have to pass a the correct identifier.

EDIT -- You can try to getAvailableIDs() and iterate through them to make sure you have the correct id.

Comment: how to get the correct IDs? can give me example for Kuala Lumpur?

Answer (score 0):

If you've read the javadoc of TimeZone carefully, the way to use getTimeZone is:
TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8")
or 
TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8")

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" ) 
).toString()
```

> 2018-01-23T18:48:32.263+08:00[Asia/Kuala_Lumpur]

## Avoid legacy classes

The Question and other Answers use troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## java.time

The modern approach uses java.time classes. Forget all about the terribly confusing `Calendar` class.

## Current moment

First get the current moment in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

## Time zone

Adjust into another time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" ) ; // Or "Asia/Kuching", etc.
```

Apply the `ZoneId` to instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` object. Both the `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` represent the same moment, the very same point on the timeline, but is viewed through a different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

## Offset

If you had only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) such as `+08:00` rather than a known [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone), you would use [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead of a `ZoneId` & `ZonedDateTime`. But a time zone is always preferable to a mere offset. A zone is a history of offsets used by the people of particular region.

## Strings

To generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString` method.

The `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard by appending the time zone name in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSS[tz]
```

Localize to the user’s preferences. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

  Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
  DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
  String output = zdt.format( f );

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant ) ;
System.out.println( "output: " + output ) ;
System.out.println( "outputLocalized (always Locale.US on IdeOne.com): " + outputLocalized ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JL9e7R). Note that IdeOne.com overrides any `Locale` setting to always use `Locale.US`.

> instant.toString(): 2018-01-23T10:48:32.263Z
>
> output: 2018-01-23T18:48:32.263+08:00[Asia/Kuala_Lumpur]
>
> ooutputLocalized (always Locale.US on IdeOne.com): Tuesday, January 23, 2018 6:48:32 PM MYT

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).