# How to convert the date String with timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone

I have some string with date format such as

```
Sat Aug 15 13:53:41 MYT 2015
```

I use SimpleDateFormate and tried to convert the String type into Date type. It converted the String type into Date type, however, the timezone "MYT" is not recognized by Java and instead it was set to the default timezone of my computer i.e. "CST". I need the time zone to be record in the Date object. How could I do it?

Comment: Your code would be helpful here.

Comment: Perhaps [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932083/problem-on-java-calendar-function) would be helpful?

Comment: @EricLo Please upload your code. Hope it will be helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the time zone in advance, you can hardcode it into the formatter like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));
Date date = format.parse("2016-01-01 00:00:00 MYT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the code

```
String dateStr = "Sat Aug 15 13:53:41 MYT 2015";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
System.out.println(date);        

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +         cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

System.out.println("formatedDate : " + formatedDate);
```

Resource Link:

1. [How to convert “ Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012” to 18/06/2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012)